# How to link two ROIs on two different images

Tags: dm-script

I wrote a little program that copies the frame and position of a ROI from an image to an other image of the same size.
What I want to do now is to connect the two ROIs in way that when I move one ROI the other one is moving accordingly.

On Dave's mitchell DM scripting website, I found that he used the function ConnectObject. but he does not explain how it works.
I read the DM3's documentation and I couldn't find any information about that function.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried till now and then ask for suggestions to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

There are two concepts here which would work. You can use one of two methods:

1) Use "ConnectObject" to attach some functionality to when a ROI is moved, i.e. when you move ROI 1 it "triggers" code which you can use to update other rois.

2) Use "ImageDisplayListeners" to attach functionality to when *any* ROI on a specific imageDisplay is moved,
i.e. when a ROI an image A is moved it triggers code which you can use to update other rois.

You will find example [code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118083/is-it-possible-for-a-digitalmicrograph-script-object-to-be-notified-of-an-roi-ch).

Answer (score 1):

For simple things there is another option:

### Adding the *identical* ROI to more than one image-display:

In this case, the ROIs are "linked" automatically, because they really are only a single object in memory (but displayed on two displays.) Changing one will change the other.
However, this linkage is "lost" if you save/load the images, because when you load the image, all ROIs (in memory) are newly created. Here is some simple example code:

```
image img1, img2
GetTwoLabeledImagesWithPrompt("Select two images of same size.", "Select", "Source", img1, "Destination", img2 )

imageDisplay disp1 = img1.ImageGetImageDisplay( 0 ) 
imageDisplay disp2 = img2.ImageGetImageDisplay( 0 ) 
number nR = disp1.ImageDisplayCountROIs()

for ( number i = 0; i<nR; i++ )
{
    ROI theROI = disp1.ImageDisplayGetROI(i)
    disp2.ImageDisplayAddROI(theROI)
}
```