# What are the methods to restrict ROI movement

Tags: dm-script

I want to allow a user to change the diameter of an oval ROI or annotation with a fixed axes ratio (for circles, the ratio is 1:1).  Also, the Oval should open up around the center only but not be allowed to shift sideways.

Currently, I have a script that reads the ROI and corrects when the user strays from the shape or the location of its center.  However, it looks rather annoying and confusing, for example when the circle is changed to an oval and then pops back to a circle. I was hoping for commands that allow e.g., resize (with the option of fixed axes ratio) but restrict (lateral) movement.

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a specific application of the [more general question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27118083/1302888).

---

The trick is to act whenever the size of a ROI is changed and then replace it with the restrictions in place. This is done by attaching a "listener" method 
which is invoked when the ROI is changed.
There are two ways one can do this for ROIs:

### 1) Attaching the listener to the *imageDisplay* on which the ROI sits

```
// EXAMPLE using ImageDisplay listener
// This will handle ALL ROIs on the display, so one would like to 
// "filter" specific ROIs. f.e. by using the ROI property "Name".
class CCircleRestrict
{
    number x0,y0
    object Init( object self, number cx, number cy ){ x0 = cx; y0 = cy; return self; }
    void OnRestrict( object self, number e_fl, ImageDisplay idisp, number r_fl, number r_fl2, ROI theROI )
    {
        if ( theROI.ROIGetName() != "special" ) return; // Skip, if it isn't "our" ROI
        if ( !theROI.ROIIsOval() ) return;  // Skip, if it isn't an oval ROI
        // get size of ROI ( as currently dragged by user )
        number t, l, b, r
        theROI.ROIGetOval( t, l, b, r )
        number radius = max( b - t, r - l ) / 2
        // Re-Set the ROI centered on x0/y0 with the new radius
        theROI.ROISetOval( y0 - radius, x0 - radius, y0 + radius, x0 + radius )
    }
}

// Main script "attaches" the display listener to 
void main()
{
    // Create and show test image 
    number size = 512
    number r1 = 20
    number r2 = 20
    number off = 100
    image test := realImage( "Test", 4, size, size )
    test.ShowImage()
    imageDisplay disp = test.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
    // Add two oval ROIs, name one of them "special" for identification
    ROI specialROI = NewROI()
    specialROI.ROISetName( "special" )
    specialROI.ROISetOval( size/2 - r1, size/2 - r1, size/2 + r1, size/2 + r1 )
    specialROI.ROISetVolatile(0)
    specialROI.ROISetColor(0.1,0.9,0.1)
    disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(specialROI)
    ROI otherROI = NewROI()
    otherROI.ROISetOval( off + size/2 - r2, off +  size/2 - r2, off +  size/2 + r2, off + size/2 + r2 )
    otherROI.ROISetVolatile(0)
    disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(otherROI)
    // Create listener object and attach listener to display
    object dispListener = Alloc(CCircleRestrict).Init( size/2, size/2 )
    disp.ImageDisplayAddEventListener( dispListener, "roi_property_changed:OnRestrict" )
}

EGUPerformActionWithAllShownImages( "Delete" )
main()
EGUPerformActionWithAllShownImages( "Arrange" )
```

### 2) Attaching the listener to the ROI object itself

```
// EXAMPLE using ROI listener
// This will handle changes a specific ROI, regardless of the display(s) it is on
class CCircleRestrict
{
    number x0,y0
    object Init( object self, number cx, number cy ){ x0 = cx; y0 = cy; return self; }
    void OnRestrict( object self, ROI theROI )
    {
        if ( !theROI.ROIIsOval() ) return;  // Skip, if it isn't an oval ROI
        // get size of ROI ( as currently dragged by user )
        number t, l, b, r
        theROI.ROIGetOval( t, l, b, r )
        number radius = max( b - t, r - l ) / 2
        // Re-Set the ROI centered on x0/y0 with the new radius
        theROI.ROISetOval( y0 - radius, x0 - radius, y0 + radius, x0 + radius )
    }
}

// Main script "attaches" the listener to the ROI
void main()
{
    // Create and show test image 
    number size = 512
    number r1 = 20
    number r2 = 20
    number off = 100
    image test := realImage( "Test", 4, size, size )
    test.ShowImage()
    imageDisplay disp = test.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
    // Add two oval ROIs
    ROI specialROI = NewROI()
    specialROI.ROISetOval( size/2 - r1, size/2 - r1, size/2 + r1, size/2 + r1 )
    specialROI.ROISetVolatile(0)
    specialROI.ROISetColor(0.1,0.9,0.1)
    disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(specialROI)
    ROI otherROI = NewROI()
    otherROI.ROISetOval( off + size/2 - r2, off +  size/2 - r2, off +  size/2 + r2, off + size/2 + r2 )
    otherROI.ROISetVolatile(0)
    disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(otherROI)
    // Create listener object and attach listener to specific ROI
    object roiListener = Alloc(CCircleRestrict).Init( size/2, size/2 )
    ConnectObject( specialROI.ROIGetID(), "changed", "EventID_Name", roiListener, "OnRestrict" )
}

EGUPerformActionWithAllShownImages( "Delete" )
main()
EGUPerformActionWithAllShownImages( "Arrange" )
```

Both examples above restrict the oval ROI to a circle, but it is straight forward to change it such that a specific aspect ratio of the oval is achieved.

> However, it is important to consider that the "newly set" and adjusted
>   ROI will itself again trigger the listener. It has to be ensured that
>   no infinite loop is created in this way, i.e. the triggering of the
>   method for the second time *must not* result in new restrictions.

A simple example for an oval ROI with a 1 : 2 aspect ratio would use a restriction method as in:

```
void OnRestrict( object self, ROI theROI )
{
    ar = 2
    if ( !theROI.ROIIsOval() ) return;  // Skip, if it isn't an oval ROI
    // get size of ROI ( as currently dragged by user )
    number t, l, b, r
    theROI.ROIGetOval( t, l, b, r )
    number w = r - l
    number h = b - t
    number newW = max( W, AR*H )
    number newH = newW/AR
    // Re-Set the ROI centered on x0/y0 with the new radius
    theROI.ROISetOval( y0 - newH/2, x0 - newW/2, y0 + newH/2, x0 + newW/2 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above specifies the type of restricitions asked for, but for completeness sake, it should also be mentioned that there are some ROI *properties* which can be useful in this context.

From the F1 help documentation:

[image: F1 help]

However, the *moveable* property supersedes the *resizable* property, i.e if you can't move, you can't resize.